# Passing table-valued parameter for IN operator

Tags: c#, sql, table-valued-parameters, in-operator

How can I pass string parameter with table-value for stored procedure in SQL Server (using c#).

My code:

C#

```
SqlParameter tvpParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
"@inoper", "'New York','Boston'");
        tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
```

Stored procedure:

```
...
WHERE
    City IN (@inoper)...
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: SQL injection prevention mechanism does not allow to put `'` into parametrised string I presume.

Comment: What should I do? There should be a way to manage that with table-valued parameter.

Comment: Don't use the accepted answer from the duplicate. The best answer there is actually #3.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you [meant 7](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6356730/23354), right? ;p (this is meant tongue-in-cheek)

Comment: @michael24B if you specifically want a TVP, you'll want a `DataTable` at the call site; you don't necessarily *need* to use a TVP, though

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, 7 is also one of several answers that I liked on that page. In fact, the only answer that I truly disliked was the accepted one.

Comment: @MarcGravell I do not want specifically TVP. I just need the fastest thing to do that. Which is it?

Comment: @Michael I'm going to go ahead and say "dapper", but I'm biased as the author